# How to make link in Link in html

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink

How to make link that will open a file located in different folder?
upward and backward!
Thanks

```
    <nav class="floatfix">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/product/index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

how to open a folder that is under products

Comment: different folder, Do you mean outside your web project folder or outside your current file location but always in the same web project folder?

Comment: Show the hierarchy of files/folder, page that has link and page that going to be link

Answer (score 0):

from current directory you can go one folder backwards using "../"

```
<a href="../sibling-product-product-folder/index.php">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I will give some folder structure. Wrapper -> Testing -> Product

Assume your HTML file located in Testing Folder. Now if you want to point any file in Wrapper, you  need to use the syntax like below.

```
<a href="../Sample.html">My Link</a>
```

If you want to point any file under Product, you need to use the syntax like below.

```
<a href="Product/Sample.html">My Link</a>
```